# How do I make a new data frame from two existing data frames in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames `df_att_transposed` and `df_1`. `df_1` has Supervisor and Name columns. The second data frame, `df_att_transposed` has attendance for all the names. My first dataframe constructor `df_1` is -

```
{'Sup': {0: 'Sup-1', 1: 'Sup-1', 2: 'Sup-1', 3: 'Sup-1', 4: 'Sup-2',....},'Name': {0: 'Name-1', 1: 'Name-2', 2: 'Name-3'...}}
```

My second data frame constructor `df_att_transposed` is -

```
{0: {0: Timestamp('2022-01-31 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2022-02-02 00:00:00'),...} 1: {0: 'P', 1: 'P', 2: 'P', 3: 'P', 4: 'P'...}}
```

In my new data frame I am adding the date (the 0th column) and the attendance column of the respective person from `df_att_transposed`. From `df_1` I am taking a row at a time containing the name and supervisor in each iteration of a for loop and adding it to all the rows in the data frame. This is how I am making a new dataframe -

```
rows = df_1.shape[0]
for i in range(rows):     
    new_df = df_att_transposed.iloc[:,[0,i+1]].copy()
    new_df['Sup'] = df_1.iloc[i]['Sup']
    new_df['Name'] = df_1.iloc[i]['Name']
```

The above code adds the data but it only keeps the data from the last iteration in `new_df`. For every iteration the previous data gets replaced. How can I keep the data from all the iterations together in the new data frame?

**Edit:** (i)The output should look like this -

```
Sup     Name       0       1 
Sup-1   Name-1  28/3/2022  P
Sup-1   Name-1  27/3/2022  P
Sup-1   Name-1  26/3/2022  P
.....
Sup-2   Name-2  28/3/2022  P
Sup-2   Name-2  27/3/2022  P
Sup-2   Name-2  26/3/2022  P
......
```

The code I have written takes a name/row from `df_1` and two columns from `df_att_transposed`, writes the data in `new_df`. Then in the next iteration, another row is taken from `df_1` and two columns from `df_att_transposed` again, and the data that was previously stored in `new_df` gets overwritten. I want the data to be appended in every iteration not replaced.

(ii) df_att_transposed looks like this(for say 5 employees) -

```
       0     1 2 3 4 5 
0  28/3/2022 P P P P P 
1  27/3/2022 P P P P P 
2  26/3/2022 P P P P P 
....
```

Comment: You should clarify a bit what you're looking for, it's kind of difficult to read you. May I suggest an example of desired output ?

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a cross merge?

```
new_df = df_1.merge(df_att_transposed, how='cross')
print(new_df)

# Output
      Sup    Name          0  1
0   Sup-1  Name-1 2022-01-31  P
1   Sup-1  Name-1 2022-02-01  P
2   Sup-1  Name-1 2022-02-02  P
3   Sup-1  Name-2 2022-01-31  P
4   Sup-1  Name-2 2022-02-01  P
5   Sup-1  Name-2 2022-02-02  P
6   Sup-1  Name-3 2022-01-31  P
7   Sup-1  Name-3 2022-02-01  P
8   Sup-1  Name-3 2022-02-02  P
9   Sup-2  Name-4 2022-01-31  P
10  Sup-2  Name-4 2022-02-01  P
11  Sup-2  Name-4 2022-02-02  P
12  Sup-2  Name-5 2022-01-31  P
13  Sup-2  Name-5 2022-02-01  P
14  Sup-2  Name-5 2022-02-02  P
```

Setup

```
>>> df_1
     Sup    Name
0  Sup-1  Name-1
1  Sup-1  Name-2
2  Sup-1  Name-3
3  Sup-2  Name-4
4  Sup-2  Name-5

>>> df_att_transposed
           0  1
0 2022-01-31  P
1 2022-02-01  P
2 2022-02-02  P
```

Comment: dff_att_transposed would have 5 attendance columns for 5 employees instead of 1. So then it would have 6 columns in total. df_1 is correct.

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `print(df_att_transposed.head())`

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: Can you check if `new_df = df_1.merge(df_att_transposed.set_index(0).stack().droplevel(1).rename(1).reset_index(), how='cross')` gives you the right output please?

Comment: This is assigning the same date to one employee. Like 2022-01-31  has been assigned to Name-1 for a number of times and then 2022-01-30 has been assigned to Name-2 and so on.

Comment: Please provide a sample with its expected output to better understanding.

Comment: `Sup1 Name-1 Date-1 P` `Sup1 Name-1 Date-1 P` `Sup1 Name-1 Date-1 P` `Sup1 Name-1 Date-1 P` .... `Sup2 Name2 Date-2 P` `Sup2 Name2 Date-2 P` `Sup2 Name2 Date-2 P`.......`Sup2 Name3 Date-3 P` `Sup2 Name3 Date-3 P` `Sup2 Name3 Date-3 P` ...

Comment: These are one below the other. I am unable to format it in the comments.

Comment: You can edit your post.